# How do I setState for nested object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

For a plugin I'm using I have to have a state that looks like this:

```
getInitialState() {
  return {
    invalid: true,
    access: {
      access_code: '',
      zipcode: '',
      password: '',
      confirm: '',
      hospital_id: '',
    },
  }
},
```

How would I set the state of hospital_id without setting the rest of access?

This seems to remove everything but hospital_id:

```
this.setState({access: {hospital_id: 1}})
```

Comment: I hope React comes out with a better way to do this, like `updateState()`, that would only update the keys passed instead of blowing away what's already there. I find all of these workarounds dangerous because it "fails" silently if somebody forgets to merge the new state with the existing state.

Comment: how is this a nested array?

Comment: It's not, it's a nested object. Vocab isn't my strong suit.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. With ECMA6, you can use the Object spread proposal (`...`) to create copies of objects with updated properties.

   ```
   this.setState({
     access: {
       ...this.state.access,
       hospital_id: 1,
     },
   });
   ```
2. You can use the native assign function on the Object (`Object.assign()`)

   ```
   this.setState({
     access: Object.assign({}, this.state.access, {
       hospital_id: 1,
     }),
   });
   ```
3. Or for the shortest version and atomic update:

   ```
    this.setState(({access}) => ({access: {
      ...access,
      hospital_id: 1,
    }});
   ```
4. And one more option is the updates addon:

   ```
   var update = require('react-addons-update');
   // per React docs 
   // https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html 
   // , you may want to change this to 
   // import update from 'immutability-helper';
   this.setState({
     access: update(this.state.access, {
       hospital_id: {$set: 1},
     })
   });
   ```

I would recommend using the first one.

Comment: Considering that React uses latest ES + Babel (for the most part), this should be the accepted answer. The Object spread operator is the most concise and easy to grep.

Comment: Apparently this method doesnt work on Safari. It behaves differently.

Comment: @Brigand Can you please elaborate more to clarify (for maybe beginners).   Just getting back into JS and react, and this is still a bit confusing (specifically the difference between in functions in the first code block).  Thanks :)

Answer (score 16):

```js
let newAccess = Object.assign({}, this.state.access);
newAccess.hospital_id = 1;
this.setState({access: newAccess});
```

Comment: you should not mutate state directly

Comment: [Do Not Modify State Directly](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)

Comment: Using setState is the suggested method for modifying the state indirectly. Now it may be that you mean let newAccess = Object.assign({}, this.state.access); should be used which did not occur to me before. In which case I would probably agree since that is the pattern I use elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

My preferred way of doing this now is as simple as:

```
let newAccess = this.state.access;
newAccess.hospital_id = 1;
setState({access: newAccess});
```

Slightly simpler than the current accepted answer.

**EDIT** (based on the question from @SILENT )

It looks like this is actually a potentially dangerous method. Further reading here [React: A (very brief) talk about immutability.](https://medium.com/pro-react/a-brief-talk-about-immutability-and-react-s-helpers-70919ab8ae7c)

Looks like a better way to do this would be:

```
let newAccess = Object.assign({}, this.state.access, {hospital_id:1});
this.setState({access: newAccess});
```

Comment: Isn't this mutating the state?

Comment: Looks like you're right. Updated the answer and changed the accepted answer to the one by @FakeRainBrigand

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be

```
const newAccess = {...this.state.access};
newAccess.hospital_id = 1;
setState({access: newAccess});
```

Use of the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_object_literals) creates a clone of `this.state.access`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue too(not the same context) anyways, i did the code below in my own work and it worked perfectly

```
this.setState({
  access: {
    ...this.state.access,
    hospital_id: 1,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way for this , is ES6 , you can update state with spread object
( in this way you re assign the "hospital_id"  ), like this :

```
this.setState({ access : {...this.state.access , hospital_id : 1 } })
```