# Updating an object with setState in React

Tags: reactjs, state

Is it at all possible to update object's properties with `setState`?

Something like:

```
this.state = {
   jasper: { name: 'jasper', age: 28 },
}
```

I have tried:

```
this.setState({jasper.name: 'someOtherName'});
```

and this:

```
this.setState({jasper: {name: 'someothername'}})
```

The first results in a syntax error and the second just does nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: second code would have worked however you would have lost the `age` property inside `jasper`.

Comment: I understand that React uses .assign() to. merge the old state object with the new object so shouldn't the second code work properly?

Answer (score 1031, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this, since state update is a [async operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately/42593250#42593250), so to update the state object, we need to use [updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) with `setState`.

**1- Simplest one:**

First create a copy of `jasper` then do the changes in that:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  let jasper = Object.assign({}, prevState.jasper);  // creating copy of state variable jasper
  jasper.name = 'someothername';                     // update the name property, assign a new value                 
  return { jasper };                                 // return new object jasper object
})
```

Instead of using `Object.assign` we can also write it like this:

```
let jasper = { ...prevState.jasper };
```

**2- Using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)**:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    jasper: {                   // object that we want to update
        ...prevState.jasper,    // keep all other key-value pairs
        name: 'something'       // update the value of specific key
    }
}))
```

**Note:** `Object.assign` and `Spread Operator` creates only [shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language), so if you have defined nested object or array of objects, you need a different approach.

---

## Updating nested state object:

Assume you have defined state as:

```
this.state = {
  food: {
    sandwich: {
      capsicum: true,
      crackers: true,
      mayonnaise: true
    },
    pizza: {
      jalapeno: true,
      extraCheese: false
    }
  }
}
```

To update extraCheese of pizza object:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  food: {
    ...prevState.food,           // copy all other key-value pairs of food object
    pizza: {                     // specific object of food object
      ...prevState.food.pizza,   // copy all pizza key-value pairs
      extraCheese: true          // update value of specific key
    }
  }
}))
```

## Updating array of objects:

Lets assume you have a todo app, and you are managing the data in this form:

```
this.state = {
  todoItems: [
    {
      name: 'Learn React Basics',
      status: 'pending'
    }, {
      name: 'Check Codebase',
      status: 'pending'
    }
  ]
}
```

To update the status of any todo object, run a map on the array and check for some unique value of each object, in case of `condition=true`, return the new object with updated value, else same object.

```
let key = 2;
this.setState(prevState => ({

  todoItems: prevState.todoItems.map(
    el => el.key === key? { ...el, status: 'done' }: el
  )

}))
```

**Suggestion:** If object doesn't have a unique value, then use array index.

Comment: The way I was trying now works though... the second way :S

Comment: @JohnSnow in you second it will remove the other properties from `jasper` object, do the `console.log(jasper)` you will see only one key `name`, age will not be there :)

Comment: True... Is the way you described the ONLY way to go about it... considering I want to use React and not Redux?

Comment: @JohnSnow, yes this way is proper if `jasper` is an `object`, don't the whether best or not, may be other better solutions are possible :)

Comment: Slightly more elegant ES6+ solution: [with spread operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34956745/2984693).

Comment: Good to mention here that neither `Object.assign` nor spread operator deep copy properties. In this way you should use workarounds like lodash `deepCopy` etc.

Comment: this.state.jasper isn't guaranteed to contain the object version you expect, right? (Referring to another answer's comment: "...in order to optimize state updates React might group multiple updates. As a consequence this.state.jasper does not necessarily contain the latest state.")

Comment: @giorgim its not a nested object, Object.assign will create a copy of the object, so `jasper.name = 'someothername';` will not affect the original object. better to try the same in console and see the output :)

Comment: @MayankShukla ok, i see now; if `jasper` had object inside then modifying that object would not be correct

Comment: I use spread operator. I added the input value to the variable `name` and use it as follows: `jasper.name: name`

Comment: How bout `let { jasper } = this.state`?

Comment: To deep copy an object (and all properties), you could always do:
`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(nestedObjToCopy))`

Comment: Is it mandatory to use the spread operator to create a new object, instead of updating the existing one?

Comment: @ankur_rajput we use spread operator to create a shallow copy, you can use Object.assign as well. Avoid the direct mutation of the state object.

Comment: I find this so cumbersome pluming so much code for evt. just updating a single element in an array in a state object or like!, Seems like a lack in the language, that there's not a simple way to do this SO trivial thing. It is so error prone as well, do a little mistake and ups, there you lost a property. I really hope someone will evt. create better implementations for these operations, either as helper functions in state management end, or maybe even a version of spread operator which can do nested update/copy.

Comment: I was struggling with the nested objects. Thanks for the clear explanation.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write all different examples, I needed the last one in particular

Comment: I find spread operator way cleaner than others.
Thanks for the explaination.<3

Answer (score 78):

This is the fastest and the most readable way:

```
this.setState({...this.state.jasper, name: 'someothername'});
```

Even if `this.state.jasper` already contains a name property, the new name `name: 'someothername'` with be used.

Comment: This solution has one big disadvantage: in order to optimize state updates React might group multiple updates. As a consequence `this.state.jasper` does not necessarily contain the latest state. Better use the notation with the `prevState`.

Answer (score 41):

Use spread operator and some ES6 here

```
this.setState({
    jasper: {
          ...this.state.jasper,
          name: 'something'
    }
})
```

Comment: This updates jasper but other properties are removed from the state.

Answer (score 33):

I know there are a lot of answers here, but I'm surprised none of them create a copy of the new object outside of setState, and then simply setState({newObject}).  Clean, concise and reliable.  So in this case:

```js
const jasper = { ...this.state.jasper, name: 'someothername' }
this.setState(() => ({ jasper }))
```

Or for a dynamic property (very useful for forms)

```js
const jasper = { ...this.state.jasper, [VarRepresentingPropertyName]: 'new value' }
this.setState(() => ({ jasper }))
```

Comment: because you've used two statements where only one is required.

Answer (score 29):

Using hook we can do following way

```
const [student, setStudent] = React.useState({name: 'jasper', age: 28});
 setStudent((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          name: 'newName',
        }));
```

Comment: Perfect! Definitely missed this in the tutorial. Haha.

Comment: Perfect! Definitely missed this in the tutorial. Haha. Sorry for copying ;)

Answer (score 13):

I used this solution.

If you have a  nested state like this:

```
this.state = {
  formInputs:{
    friendName:{
      value:'',
      isValid:false,
      errorMsg:''
    },
    friendEmail:{
      value:'',
      isValid:false,
      errorMsg:''
    }
  }
}
```

you can declare the handleChange function that copy current status and re-assigns it with changed values

```
handleChange(el) {
    let inputName = el.target.name;
    let inputValue = el.target.value;

    let statusCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    statusCopy.formInputs[inputName].value = inputValue;

    this.setState(statusCopy);
  }
```

here the html with the event listener. Make sure to use the same name used into state object (in this case 'friendName')

```
<input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} " name="friendName" />
```

Comment: This worked for me, except I had to use this instead: `statusCopy.formInputs[inputName] = inputValue;`

Answer (score 11):

*try this,it should work fine*

```
this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.jasper,{name:'someOtherName'}));
```

Comment: You are mutating the state object directly. To use this approach, add a new object as the source :
```Object.assign({}, this.state.jasper, {name:'someOtherName'})```

Answer (score 7):

Create a state object

```
this.state = {
  objName: {
    propertyOne: "",
    propertyTwo: ""
  }
};
```

Update state using `setState`

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  objName: {
    ...prevState.objName,
    propertyOne: "Updated Value",
    propertyTwo: "Updated value"
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 7):

**Using hooks in Functional Component:**

```
const [state, setState] = useState({jasper: { name: 'jasper', age: 28 }})
const nameChangeHandler = () => {
      setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            prevState.jasper.name = "Anurag",
            prevState.jasper.age = 28
      })
    )
}
```

In these cases It is recommended to use callback-based approach to update the state , because using this approach it is ensured that previously states are fully updated and we're updating based on previously updated state.

Answer (score 5):

this is another solution using [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) immutabe utility, very suited for deeply nested objects with ease, and you should not care about mutation

```
this.setState(
    produce(draft => {
       draft.jasper.name = 'someothername'
    })
)
```

Answer (score 4):

### In case of updating an object where keys are string

e.g. let say your state object is

```
serviceDays: {
    Sunday: true,
    Monday: true,
    Tuesday: false,
    Wednesday: true,
    Thurday: false,
    Friday: true,
    Saturday: true
  }
```

so you can update in following way

```
const onDayClick = day => {
  const { serviceDays } = this.state
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    serviceDays: {
      ...prevState.serviceDays,
      [day]: serviceDays[day] ? false : true
    }
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first case is indeed a syntax error.

Since I can't see the rest of your component, it's hard to see why you're nesting objects in your state here. It's not a good idea to nest objects in component state. Try setting your initial state to be:

```
this.state = {
  name: 'jasper',
  age: 28
}
```

That way, if you want to update the name, you can just call:

```
this.setState({
  name: 'Sean'
});
```

Will that achieve what you're aiming for?

For larger, more complex data stores, I would use something like Redux. But that's much more advanced.

The general rule with component state is to use it only to manage UI state of the component (e.g. active, timers, etc.)

Check out these references:

- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state
- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: I only used that as an example, the object must be nested.. I probably should be using Redux but I am trying to understand React fundementals..

Comment: Yeah, I would stay away from Redux for now. While you're learning the fundamentals, try to keep your data simple. That'll help you avoid odd cases that trip you up. 

Answer (score 3):

Another option: define your variable out of the *Jasper* object and then just call a variable.

**Spread operator: ES6**

```
this.state = {  jasper: { name: 'jasper', age: 28 } } 

let foo = "something that needs to be saved into state" 

this.setState(prevState => ({
    jasper: {
        ...jasper.entity,
        foo
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try with this:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
   prevState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.jasper));
   prevState.name = 'someOtherName';
   return {jasper: prevState}
})
```

or for other property:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
   prevState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.jasper));
   prevState.age = 'someOtherAge';
   return {jasper: prevState}
})
```

Or you can use handleChage function:

```
handleChage(event) {
   const {name, value} = event.target;
    this.setState(prevState => {
       prevState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.jasper));
       prevState[name] = value;
       return {jasper: prevState}
    })
}
```

and HTML code:

```
<input 
   type={"text"} 
   name={"name"} 
   value={this.state.jasper.name} 
   onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
<br/>
<input 
   type={"text"} 
   name={"age"} 
   value={this.state.jasper.age} 
   onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: This works without JSON.stringify ..

this.setState(prevState => {
   prevState = this.state.document;
   prevState.ValidDate = event.target.value;
   prevState.ValidDateFormat = dayFormat;
   return {document: prevState}
  });

..Where document is state type object..

Answer (score 3):

**You can try with this**:
 (**Note**: name of input tag === field of object)

```
<input name="myField" type="text" 
      value={this.state.myObject.myField} 
     onChange={this.handleChangeInpForm}>
</input>

-----------------------------------------------------------
handleChangeInpForm = (e) => {
   let newObject = this.state.myObject;
   newObject[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
   this.setState({
     myObject: newObject 
   })
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 2):

Simple and dynamic way.

This will do the job, but you need to set all the ids to the parent so the parent will point to the name of the object, being id = "jasper" and name the name of the input element = property inside of the object jasper.

```
handleChangeObj = ({target: { id , name , value}}) => this.setState({ [id]: { ...this.state[id] , [name]: value } });
```

Comment: I agree with first line, as this is the only thing that worked for my object of objects in state! Also it cleared where I was stuck in updating my data. By far the most simple and dynamic way... Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

**Without using Async and Await Use this...**

```
funCall(){    
     this.setState({...this.state.jasper, name: 'someothername'});
}
```

**If you using with Async And Await use this...**

```
async funCall(){
      await this.setState({...this.state.jasper, name: 'someothername'});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, following Alberto Piras solution, if you don't want to copy all the "state" object:

```
handleChange(el) {
    let inputName = el.target.name;
    let inputValue = el.target.value;

    let jasperCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state.jasper);
    jasperCopy[inputName].name = inputValue;

    this.setState({jasper: jasperCopy});
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
const { jasper } = this.state; //Gets the object from state
jasper.name = 'A new name'; //do whatever you want with the object
this.setState({jasper}); //Replace the object in state
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the input html input name attribute we can have a more dynamic approach in order to update an object properties.

**DOM**
[html input name attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp)

```
<input type="text" name="fname" handleChange={(e: any) => { updatePerson(e) }}/>
<input type="text" name="lname" handleChange={(e: any) => { updatePerson(e) }}/>
```

**React / TSX**
[object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
const [person, setPerson] = useState<IPerson>({});

   function updatePerson(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void {
        const { name, value } = e.currentTarget;

        setPerson(prevState => {
            const newState = Object.assign(person, { [name]: value })
            return { ...prevState, ...newState };
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

*Sample FC:*

```
   const [formData, setformData] = useState({
           project_admin_permissions: {
              task_forms: false,
              auto_assign_rules: false,
              project_notes: true,
              alerts: false,
              update_criteria: true,
              project_flow: false,
              reports: false,
            }
        
          })
    
     const handleChangeCheckBox = (e) => {
       setformData({
          ...formData, project_admin_permissions: { ...formData.project_admin_permissions, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked }
    
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This setup worked for me:

```
let newState = this.state.jasper;
newState.name = 'someOtherName';

this.setState({newState: newState});

console.log(this.state.jasper.name); //someOtherName
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach doesn't work because `{name: 'someothername'}` equals `{name: 'someothername', age: undefined}`, so the`undefined` would overwrite original age value.

When it comes to change state in nested objects, a good approach would be [Immutable.js](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/)

```
this.state = {
  jasper: Record({name: 'jasper', age: 28})
}

const {jasper} = this.state
this.setState({jasper: jasper.set(name, 'someothername')})
```