# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a user object where they are able to edit their info (phone number, email, etc)

I am unable to access the input's `name` inside the `setState` callback and keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null`

However when I log the `event.target.name` it shows to be there.

When I change a simple state it works:

Assuming the state value is the same as the target name.

```
this.setState({ [event.target.name]: value });
```

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638938/updating-an-object-with-setstate-in-react) post to update the user object.

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I could not find what I was looking for.

```
  handleUserChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.name);
    const value = event.target.value
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      user: {...prevState.user, [event.target.name]: value }
    }))

  }
```

Edit: I am binding it properly in the class constructor like so:

```
contructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ...
    this.handleUserChange = this.handleUserChange.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: are you getting a console.log for the value?

Comment: Can you show us the code inside the _render_ method where you bind the _handleUserChange_ to the component?

Answer (score 14):

React is recycling this event. So the async call to **setState** wont know the value of **event.target.name** since the event is already gone. You need to make a copy of the value the same as you did with **event.target.value**.

```js
 handleUserChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.name);
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      user: {...prevState.user, [name]: value }
    }))

  }
```

From the docs: [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#event-pooling)

Other solution:

```js
handleUserChange(event) {
    event.persist();
    const value = event.target.value;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      user: {...prevState.user, [event.target.name]: value }
    }))

  }
```

Persists the values of the event.

Comment: This did the trick! I did not know that React recycles the event. Is this included in the docs somewhere?

Comment: I posted a link with the relevant docs for it inside the answer.