# setting a single property using setState for an object in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, setstate

I'm trying to update the property 'name' of my object person using setState. But it doesn't seem to work. 
I'm getting the 'newName' through user input.

What am I missing here?

```
this.setState({ person: { name: newName } });
```

Comment: Can you share how `this.state` looks?

Comment: Some more context would be a big help, the full source of your component for example. At the very least, the shape of your state and the function that this `setState` is being done in. I suspect it's an issue with how `setState` only merges in the top level of object keys

Comment: by this way, person object will loose all other keys, only name will be their after update, check this answer: [updating an object with setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638938/updating-an-object-with-setstate-in-react/43639228#43639228)

Comment: `this.setState(state => ({ person: Object.assign({}, state.person, { name: newName }) }));`

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Comment: Here's how my person object looks like ... person {
 name: John,
 age: 25,
 address: {},
 qualification: {}
}

Answer (score 1):

```js
class TestJS extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            person : {name : "DefaultName", age : 56}
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState(state => ({ person: Object.assign({}, state.person, { name: "sdsds" }) }));
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div id="root">
                {this.state.person.name}
                {this.state.person.age}
                <p>Hello world</p>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default TestJS;
```

Comment: Does it have any performance issues if I use this - this.setState(prevState => ({ person: { ...prevState.person, name: newName } }));