# How to update one part of state with setState

Tags: reactjs

i'm trying to use setState to update one property of a sub object of the state.  What is the correct way to do this? I want to access the state and define which part I want to update, as opposed to update the entire state with a new state.  Hope that makes sense...

```
class BooksApp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    books: []
  }

componentDidMount() {
  BooksAPI.getAll().then((books) => {
    this.setState({books})
  })
}
selectStateUpdate = (book,shelf) => {
  this.updateShelf(book, shelf);

}
updateShelf = (book, shelf) => {
  BooksAPI.update(book, shelf)
  .then(() => {
    for (var i=0; this.state.length < i; i++) {
      if (this.state.title === book.title) {
        this.setState({
          books[i].shelf: book.shelf
        })
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating an object with setState in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638938/updating-an-object-with-setstate-in-react)

Comment: I think you are asking how to just update particular entry in the `books` array instead of the whole `books` when only part of it change. Unfortunately it is not doable. @Ivan Burnaev answer is the way to do it, which will only trigger 1 event to let the component know that `state` has been change.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your state changing part to:

```
this.setState({
  books: this.state.books.map((item, index) => 
    index === i ? {...item, shelf: book.shelf} : item
  )
})
```