# In react hooks how do I pass a newly created object to a state object?

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

How do I pass `err` to `errors : {}` here ?

```
const data = { name: "", errors: {} }
const [values, setValues] = useState(data)
const handleSubmit = () => {
     const err = validate();  // I receive an object in err
    setValues({ ...values, errors: err }) // I cant set err to //errors: {} above
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the function is case-sensitive, does it work if you use `useState` instead of `usestate`? Your use of `setValues()` to set `errors` looks correct to me.

Comment: the spelling is correct in my VS code

Comment: The current code would work fine, if validate is a synchronous method

Comment: Seems to work just fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-tree-9tuh1 -- whatever the problem is, it's not with this part of your code.

Comment: Take a loot at this question about updating nested objects with `useState` hook: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342406/updating-and-merging-state-object-using-react-usestate-hook)

Comment: Or piggybacking on @ShubhamKhatri with async/await: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-tree-e4lgf

Answer (score 2):

From [React DOCs - State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), we get that:

> State variables can hold objects and arrays just fine, so you can still group related data together. However, **unlike this.setState in a class, updating a state variable always replaces it instead of merging it.**

Also, from [Hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables):

> Now let’s say we want to write some logic that changes `left` and `top` when the user moves their mouse. Note **how we have to merge these fields into the previous state object manually:**
>
> ```
> function handleWindowMouseMove(e) {
>      // Spreading "...state" ensures we don't "lose" width and height
>      setState(state => ({ ...state, left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY }));
>    }
> ```

Therefore, the way you're currently doing it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

They way you propose may work only if the method `validate()` returns an object.

In case that `validate()` returns a string, array... the assignment `setValues({ ...values, errors: err })`  may break, since `errors` is expecting an **object**