# React - useState doesn't update state on setInterval

Tags: reactjs

The state doesn't update the value even though I'm setting it to the oldvalue + 1.
When logging out the values of `ltrNewValue` or `rtlNewValue` it's always the same. It's as it's being overwritten by the initial state.

```
const Row = (props) => {
  const [rowState, setRowState] = useState({
    renderInterval: null,
    value: 0,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(counterIntervalFunction, props.speed);
    setRowState({ ...rowState, renderInterval: interval });
  }, []);

  const counterIntervalFunction = () => {
    if (props.isRunning && props.direction === 'ltr') {
      const ltrNewValue = rowState.value === 2 ? 0 : rowState.value + 1;
      console.log(ltrNewValue); // always 1
       setRowState({ ...rowState, value: ltrNewValue });
      console.log(rowState.value); // always 0
      props.setRotatingValue(props.index, rowState.value);
    } else if (props.isRunning && props.direction === 'rtl') {
      const rtlNewValue = rowState.value === 0 ? 2 : rowState.value - 1;
      setRowState({ ...rowState, value: rtlNewValue });
      props.setRotatingValue(props.index, rowState.value);
    } else {
      clearCounterInterval();
    }
  };
```

My end goal is to increment the `rowState.value` up to `2` and then setting it to `0` in a infinite loop. How do I do this correctly?

Comment: You might be better off just separating out `value` into its own piece of state.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating and merging state object using React useState() hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342406/updating-and-merging-state-object-using-react-usestate-hook)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not certain, but it looks like you have a problem with a stale callback here.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(counterIntervalFunction, props.speed);
    setRowState({ ...rowState, renderInterval: interval });
  }, []);
```

This effect only runs once - When the component is mounted the first time. It uses the `counterIntervalFunction` function for the interval:

```
  const counterIntervalFunction = () => {
    if (props.isRunning && props.direction === 'ltr') {
      const ltrNewValue = rowState.value === 2 ? 0 : rowState.value + 1;
      console.log(ltrNewValue); // always 1
       setRowState({ ...rowState, value: ltrNewValue });
      console.log(rowState.value); // always 0
      props.setRotatingValue(props.index, rowState.value);
    } else if (props.isRunning && props.direction === 'rtl') {
      const rtlNewValue = rowState.value === 0 ? 2 : rowState.value - 1;
      setRowState({ ...rowState, value: rtlNewValue });
      props.setRotatingValue(props.index, rowState.value);
    } else {
      clearCounterInterval();
    }
  };
```

The `counterIntervalFunction` captures the reference of `props` and uses it to determine what to display to the user. However, *because* this function is only run when the component is mounted, the event will only be run with the props passed to the function originally! You can see an example of this happening in [this codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-architecture-chpig)

This is why you should put all external dependencies inside of the dependencies array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(counterIntervalFunction, props.speed); 
  setRowState({ ...rowState, renderInterval: interval }); 
}, [counterIntervalFunction, props.speed, rowState]);
```

However, this will cause an infinite loop.

Setting state in `useEffect` is usually considered a bad idea, because it tends to lead to infinite loops - changing the state will cause the component to re-render, causing another effect to be triggered etc.

Looking at your effect loop, what you're actually interested in is capturing a reference to the interval. This interval won't actually have any impact on the component if it changes, so instead of using state, we can use a ref to keep track of it. Refs don't cause re-renders. This also means we can change `value` to be a stand-alone value.

Because we now no longer depend on `rowState`, we can remove that from the dependencies array, preventing an infinite render. Now our effect only depends on `props.speed` and `counterIntervalFunction`:

```
  const renderInterval = React.useRef();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    renderInterval.current = setInterval(counterIntervalFunction, props.speed);
    return () => {
      cancelInterval(renderInterval.current);
    };
  }, [props.speed, counterIntervalFunction]);
```

This will work, but because `counterIntervalFunction` is defined inline, it will be recreated every render, causing the effect to trigger every render. We can stablize it with `React.useCallback()`. We'll also want to add all the dependencies of this function to ensure that we don't capture stale references to props and we can change `setRowState` to `setValue`. Finally, because the interval is cancelled by `useEffect`, we don't need to call `clearCounterInterval` anymore.

```
  const counterIntervalFunction = React.useCallback(() => {
    if (props.isRunning && props.direction === 'ltr') {
      const ltrNewValue = value === 2 ? 0 : value + 1;
      setValue(ltrNewValue);
      props.setRotatingValue(props.index, ltrNewValue);
    } else if (isRunning && props.direction === 'rtl') {
      const rtlNewValue = value === 0 ? 2 : value - 1;
      setValue(rtlNewValue);
      props.setRotatingValue(props.index, rtlNewValue);
    }
  }, [value, props]);
```

This can be simplified even further by moving the required props to the arguments:

```
  const counterIntervalFunction = React.useCallback((isRunning, direction, setRotatingValue, index) => {
    if (isRunning === false) {
      return;
    }

    if (direction === 'ltr') {
      const ltrNewValue = value === 2 ? 0 : value + 1;
      setValue(ltrNewValue);
      setRotatingValue(index, ltrNewValue);
    } else if (props.direction === 'rtl') {
      const rtlNewValue = value === 0 ? 2 : value - 1;
      setValue(rtlNewValue);
      setRotatingValue(index, rtlNewValue);
    }
  }, [value]);
```

This could be *even simpler* if not for `setRotatingValue`: Right now, you have a component that both maintains it's own state *and* tells the parent when its state changes. You should be aware that the component state `value` might not necessarily update when you call it, but `setRotatingValue` absolutely will. This may lead to a situation where the *parent* sees a different state than the child does. I would recommend altering the way your data flows such that it's the parent that owns the current value and passes it via props, *not* the child.

This gives us the following code to finish off:

```
function Row = (props) => {
  const renderInterval = React.useRef();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    renderInterval.current = setInterval(counterIntervalFunction, props.isRunning, props.direction, props.setRotatingValue, props.index);
    return () => {
      cancelInterval(renderInterval.current);
    };
  }, [props, counterIntervalFunction]);

  const counterIntervalFunction = React.useCallback((isRunning, direction, setRotatingValue, index) => {
    if (isRunning === false) {
      return;
    }

    if (direction === 'ltr') {
      const ltrNewValue = value === 2 ? 0 : value + 1;
      setValue(ltrNewValue);
      setRotatingValue(index, ltrNewValue);
    } else if (props.direction === 'rtl') {
      const rtlNewValue = value === 0 ? 2 : value - 1;
      setValue(rtlNewValue);
      setRotatingValue(index, rtlNewValue);
    }
  }, [value]);


  ...
}
```

In this code, you'll notice that we run the effect every time the props or the function changes. This will mean that, unfortunately, the effect will return every loop, because we need to keep a fresh reference to `value`. This component will always have this problem unless you refactor `counterIntervalFunction` to not notify the parent with `setRotatingValue` *or* for this function to not contain its own state. An alternatively way we could solve this would be using the function form of `setValue`:

```
  const counterIntervalFunction = React.useCallback((isRunning, direction, setRotatingValue, index) => {
    if (isRunning === false) {
      return;
    }

    setValue(value => {
      if (direction === 'ltr') {
        return value === 2 ? 0 : value + 1;
      } else if (direction ==' rtl') {
        return value === 0 ? 2 : value - 1;
      }
    })
  }, []);
```

Because the state update is not guaranteed to run synchronously, there's no way to extract the value from the `setValue` call and then call the `setRotatingValue` function, though. :( You could *potentially* call `setRotatingValue` inside of the `setValue` callback but that gives me the heebie geebies.

Comment: This solution fixes the issue for me. Thank you!

Comment: Good deep dive to the problem!

Comment: Very good deep explanation 
If you need to get it clear about possible ways to hack setInterval this article is a nice addition https://itnext.io/how-to-work-with-intervals-in-react-hooks-f29892d650f2

Answer (score 1):

It's an interval and it may mess things up when you call setState directly by relying on the old state by the name rowState, try this:

```
   setRowState(oldstate=> { ...rowState, value: oldstate.value+1 });
```

Comment: Exactly what's described in the dupe.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate.