# how do I use state in tsx file that just has a default function

Tags: typescript, react-native

I had create a new react native project by init a tabs (TypeScript) .
this example has 2 tabs , each tab content in a tsx file that just have a single

```
export default function
```

and how can I use sates in that function .

[image]

and how can I use sates in that function .

Comment: Same as for every component. Export default just tells other files what is exported by default from this file.

Comment: Why do you have to use state in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use state in a functional component as follows: (example taken from this link: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

To break this down,

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

basically means the same thing as

```
this.state = {
    count: 0; // 0 is what the count state variable initializes to
}

setCount(newStateCount) {
    count = newStateCount; // you change the state using setCount(1), for example. 
    // now count goes from 0 to 1 in this case.
}
```

React basically does the implementation of both for you in that single line, and all you have to do is call setCount in order to change the count state instead of `this.state.count = newValue`.

In response to the comment under this original answer: You can set state for multiple properties like so: [how to write a multi lines state with Hooks useState in ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62012191/how-to-write-a-multi-lines-state-with-hooks-usestate-in-reactjs)

```
   const [state, setState] = useState({
        step: 1,
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        jobTitle: '',
        jobCompany: '',
        jobLocation: '',
    });
   // Setting state like:
   setState(prev=>{...prev,firstName:'Joey'});
```

Comment: Thank you , it's means I have to create a function like const [count, setCount] = useState(0); for each state's property set ?

Comment: Yes. So if you have 2 properties, then you'd have two lines similar to that.

Comment: could you please  write 2 properties in 1 line please ? thanks in advance . and it's for TypeScript yes ?

Comment: @kiamoz I have edited the answer with an example on how to set state for multiple properties using the same useState call. It will work with typescript.

Comment: thank for all your helps , could you please mark + my question  ? I ca't ask more  question ..

Comment: @Andrew  I have other question , what means prev in  setState(prev=>{...prev,firstName:'Joey'}); thank you

Comment: in that context, it just keeps the previous values the same (whatever they are in state) and just updates the first name. for information the actual operator (...) check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 1):

Using state in function components was made possible through React Hooks: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

So, you can do something like this, with the `useState` hook:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```