# React+JavaScript: Item appears on console but then disappears

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to console log the two fields from my sign up page. However, the item appears in the console for about a second and then disappears. Any help is appreciated. Please find my code for the sign up below

```
  export default function SignUp() {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = React.useState("");
  const [lastName, setLastName] = React.useState("");

  let sign = () => {
    console.log(firstName);
  };

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign up
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                autoComplete="fname"
                name="firstName"
                id="firstName"
                label="First Name"
                autoFocus
                onChange={(event) => setFirstName(event.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                id="lastName"
                label="Last Name"
                name="lastName"
                autoComplete="lname"
                onChange={(event) => setLastName(event.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            className={classes.submit}
            onClick={sign}
          >
            Sign Up
          </Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are submitting the form without preventing the default (refreshing the page). Make sure you're passing your `sign` function to the `form`'s `onSubmit` prop, and then make sure your `sign` is something along these lines:

```
let sign = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(firstName);
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked it appears in the console now. Since there are two fields, can you advise how I can make an object out of them or should I make a new ques for that

Comment: @new_hello_world to manage a [state object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55342406/1218980).

Comment: Please mark the answer as the accepted answer if it answers you question. Check @EmileBergeron comment for creating the object :)