# React useState update based on a variables previous value

Tags: reactjs, use-state

The react.js site has the following code on [this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
...
<button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
```

But since count is updated based on its previous value, shouldn't the second line
be

```
<button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating and merging state object using React useState() hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342406/updating-and-merging-state-object-using-react-usestate-hook).
~ * ~
[This fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55342681) shows an example of when not using a function leads to the wrong behavior.

Comment: *count is never updated based on its previous value. it gets updated based on its current value.*
That's just playing around with words.
The *current* value will become the *previous* value as soon as the new state is entered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It usually isn't necessary.

The stateful `count` variable that the currently active click listener closes over will contain, at any given point in time, the current count. If you click 3 times, the component will re-render 3 times, and the `count` closed over by the currently attached listener will contain 3.

The time where you would need to use the callback form you're thinking of would be if you wanted to pass the setter function somewhere *else* (such as to a child component) and didn't want the child component to have to take the `count` as a prop as well - that makes for some messy boilerplate, especially when components get pretty nested.

You might also use the callback form in the current component if you called the callback in a function that *doesn't* get a new closure every render, such as for `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
  }, 1000);
}, []);
```

Because the effect hook there only runs on mount, the `count` variable it could see would be only the initial 0 value - so you have to use the callback form instead.