# React Native Basic Form onChangeText not updating state completely

Tags: javascript, forms, react-native, onchange

I have been trying to create and submit a basic React Native form without any library. Currently, for testing purposes, I have included only 3 `TextInput`(s) only.

[image]

As soon as the form is submitted only the values of the last `TextInput`, `password` here, is shown updated in the state object (in the console). The first two `TextInput` fields values remain empty as the initial state.

I tried lots of patterns to pass the data from the input fields using the method `onChangeText()`, but nothing seems to work for me. No matter how many input fields, only the last input field's state is available in the console. Not sure where things are going wrong. Here is the snack expo link to reciprocate the issue:

https://snack.expo.io/0DP-pi6bn

This might be a silly issue that I am unable to figure out, but any help to resolve the same, will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In your example, you are replacing the state with the last value. useState doesn't   do  partial updates like class components, you will need to get the prev state and use the spread  operator to extract it's  values. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342406/updating-and-merging-state-object-using-react-usestate-hook

Comment: @nipuna777 That was so dumb of me. Thanks for pointing it out. It works perfectly fine now.

Comment: Easy mistake to make! Happy to help.