# How do I mutate Chart.js data using React state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

In my project I wish to toggle between two sets of data: total hours worked each day in current week, and total hours worked each month in the current year. I am able to achieve Chart.js label manipulation in my button handlers, but I am unable to modify the state's data property. What am I missing here? Thank you for helping.

**Note:** The commented code produce this error statement when uncommented:
`Uncaught TypeError: nextDatasets.map is not a function`

LineChart.js

```
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
    labels: Object.keys(daysData),
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Hours worked",
        data: Object.values(daysData),
        backgroundColor: "red",
        borderColor: "black",
        borderWidth: 2,
      },
    ],
  });

  const onShowWeeklyHandler = () => {
    setUserData({ labels: Object.keys(daysData) });
    // setUserData({ datasets: { data: Object.keys(daysData) } });
  };

  const onShowMonthlyHandler = () => {
    setUserData({ labels: Object.keys(monthsData) });
    // setUserData({ datasets: { data: Object.keys(monthsData) } });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be encountering issues because you are trying to shallow merge state with the useState hook. React does not support this. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342406/updating-and-merging-state-object-using-react-usestate-hook) for more info.

If that does not solve your issue, have you looked into [react-chartjs-2](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/docs/working-with-datasets)? You might be able to achieve what you want doing something like the following.

In your parent component (the one that contains the chart):

```
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2"; // import whatever chart type you need
...

const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
    labels: Object.keys(daysData),
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Hours worked",
        data: Object.values(daysData),
        backgroundColor: "red",
        borderColor: "black",
        borderWidth: 2,
      },
    ],
  });
```

Then your handlers can be:

```
  const onShowWeeklyHandler = () => {
    setUserData({
      ...userData,
      datasets: {
        ...userData.datasets,
        labels: Object.keys(daysData),
        data: Object.values(daysData),
      },
    });
  };

  const onShowMonthlyHandler = () => {
    setUserData({
      ...userData,
      datasets: {
        ...userData.datasets,
        labels: Object.keys(monthsData),
        data: Object.values(monthsData),
      },
    });
  };
```

Finally:

```
return <Bar data={userData.datasets} />; // adapt for whatever chart type you need
```