# Is there a way to update only one property of an object while keeping the others the same?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to make a basketball scoreboard app in React and have each team as it's own object with score, field goals made, and field goal attempts as properties. I have buttons that increment all of these properties and I am trying to create a button to account for missed shots using setState on field goal attempts(fga), but it also updates the state for the other properties resetting their state to 0. Is there a way to use setState on a specific property without touching the rest?

Object:

```
  const [team1, setTeam1] = useState({
    score: 0,
    fgm: 0,
    fga: 0,
    threePm: 0,
  });
```

Button:

```
       <button
          id="miss"
          onClick={() =>
            setTeam1({
              fga: team1.fga + 1,
            })
          }
        >
          Miss
        </button>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342406/updating-and-merging-state-object-using-react-usestate-hook has the answer, but in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the previous state, spread it, and add the updated property to create the new state:

```
onClick={() =>
  setTeam1(team1=> ({
    ...team1,
    fga: team1.fga + 1,
  }))
}
```

When creating a new state, based on the previous state, it's better to use and [updater function](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state). The updater function is called with the previous state. Take the previous state, spread it into a new object, and add the updated property:

```
onClick={() =>
  setTeam1(prev => ({
    ...prev,
    fga: prev.fga + 1,
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, use a spread operator to make a copy of the previous state and set it to your new state, then we set the new property like so:

```
<button id="miss"
  onClick={() => setTeam1({...team1, fga: team1.fga + 1})}
>
 Miss
</button>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
    // Define an object with multiple properties
let person = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 25,
  occupation: 'Engineer'
};

// Update only the 'age' property while keeping others unchanged
let updatedPerson = {
  ...<link>person</link>,  // Spread the properties of the original object
  age: 26    // Update the 'age' property
};

// Output the updated object
console.log(updatedPerson);
```

Comment: Did you generate this with ChatGPT or something?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).