# Using React Hooks with more than one Key/Value Pair in State Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wonder what the best way is to define more than one `key/value` pair for the `state` in a `Functional Component`.

In a class I would initialithe `State` like

```
this.state = {
    first: 'foo',
    second: 'bar'
};
```

To update the `State` I call

```
this.setState({
    first: 'foobar',
    second: 'barfoo'
});
```

Now with `React Hooks` I initialize the `State` like so.

```
const [first, setfirst] = useState('foo');
const [second, setSecond] = useState('bar');
```

To update the `State` I call:

```
setFirst = 'foobar';
setSecond = 'barfoo';
```

But, IMHO, that is not ideal. I have to rewrite `const [x, setX] = useState(...);` everytime I want to add a new `key/value` pair to the `State object`. Boilerplate. I further always have to keep in mind the "setter" name of `x`, which is `setX`. That will get messy, if the `State object` grows.

It would be nicer if I could simply call

```
setState(first: 'foobar', second: 'barfoo');
```

But I am not sure how to initialize the `State object` properly/what is the best way to do that.

Comment: Have you found the best way to do this? I want to avoid re-rendering multiple child components when using setState

Comment: @UMR use the accepted answer.

Comment: but you forgot to accept an answer...I use combination of React.memo and useReducer  @Stophface

Comment: @UMR There is an accepted answer with seven Upvotes... The one from Monika Mangal. The answer provided by Alireza HI works too... Look closely. I think what you want to achive is different from what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the whole object using useState like as follows -

```
const [stateObj, setStateObj] = useState({first:'foobar', second:'barfoo'});
```

and then to update the state -

```
setStateObj({first:'foobarnew', second:'barfoonew'})
```

Comment: Just do not forget to spread the `state` if you don't set all your state like this. Old `this.setState()` updates the related properties and merge the changed ones with the state but with hooks, the state always is overwritten.

Answer (score 8):

**Using object as the initial value**

You can use a `javascript object` as your value.
This way you can put more variables in your object and in one place.
So your code would be like below:

```
const [example, setExample] = useState({first:'foobar', second:barfoo''});
```

Then you can update it like this:

```
setExample({...example,first:'new foobar'})
setExample({...example,second:'new foobar second'})
```

This type of `setting` is deconstruct your previous values and is replacing your new values with the old ones.

Using this object you just need to add your new `property` to the initialize of `example` and to places which you need to set it.

As a complex example you can reach this link:

> [React Hooks useState() with Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150783/react-hooks-usestate-with-object)

---

**Notice** (updating the variable)

If you just update it using `{first:'new foobar'}` and don't include the `second` in your properties you may loose the old value of second. So use the `...example` to have the old value of `second`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to go for reducer hooks. React official site says if you have complex state rather go for **userReducer** hook.

```
const initialState = {
first: 'foo',
second: 'bar'
};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'updateFirst':
      return {...state, first: 'fooBar' };
    case 'updateSecond':
      return {...state, second: 'barfoo' };
    case 'updateBoth':
      return {...state, second: 'barfoo',first: 'fooBar' };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Component() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <>
      {state.first}
      {state.second}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'updateFirst'})}>UpdateFirst</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'updateSecond'})}>UpdateSecond</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'updateBoth'})}>UpdateBoth</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Code : https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-rosalind-9oiow

Comment: too much boilerplate imo for such a simple thing

Answer (score 0):

**From React docs**: `useReducer` is usually preferable to `useState` when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state depends on the previous one. useReducer also lets you optimize performance for components that trigger deep updates because you can pass dispatch down instead of callbacks.

```
const initialState = { first: '', second: '' };

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'doFirst':
      return {...state, first: 'newFirst' };
    case 'doSecond':
      return {...state, second: 'newSecond' };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Component() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <>
      {state.first}
      {state.second}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'doFirst'})}></button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'doSecond'})}></button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make your own hook to do this !

```
function useMultipleStates() {
    const [first setFirst] = useState('foo');
    const [second, setSecond] = useState('bar');

    const setState = (f, s) => {
        setFirst(f);
        setSecond(s);
    }

    return {
        first,
        second,
        setState,
    }
}
```

You can adapt this to your needs, but if should give you an idea on how to do it.

Comment: That is even more boilerplate, overhead, errorloaden.