# How to set state in nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Would like to know if there is a way to update nested object states in React using **useState()**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const MyComp = () => {

  const [colors, setColors] = useState({colorA: 'RED', colorB: 'PURPLE'});

  return (
    <div>
       <span>{colors.colorB}</span>
       <button onClick={() => setColors({...colors, colors: { colorB: 'WHITE'}})}>CLICK ME</button>
    </div>
  )
}


export default MyComp;
```

I was thinking to use **useReducer()** but I read that It's normally use for more complex states and maybe there is a solution for this case just using **useState()**

Any ideas?

Thx in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks useState() with Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150783/react-hooks-usestate-with-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have already done the spread, it will have the property **colorB**, you just need to update with new value

```
const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setColors({ ...colors, colorB: "WHITE" });
  };
```

making it into a function will be more readable.

**Code**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const MyComp = () => {
  const [colors, setColors] = useState({ colorA: "RED", colorB: "PURPLE" });

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setColors({ ...colors, colorB: "WHITE" });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{colors.colorB}</span>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>CLICK ME</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComp;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<MyComp />, rootElement);
```

Working [Codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-silence-dikgt)

Answer (score 4):

`colors` already is the whole object, you don't need to declare as a property.

`spread` the original object and override `colorB`

```
() => setColors({...colors, colorB: 'WHITE'})
```

Answer (score 4):

You are updating the state in a wrong way. Change your button statement to below,

```
<button onClick={() => setColors({...colors, colorB: 'WHITE'})}>CLICK ME</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

**USE**

```
setColors({...colors, colorB: 'WHITE'})
```

**INSTEAD OF**

```
setColors({...colors, colors: { colorB: 'WHITE'}})
```

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use functional form of `setState` for this, since the next state value depends on the current value of the state:

```
 return (
    <div>
      <span>{colors.colorB}</span>
      <button
        onClick={() => setColors(currentColors => ({ ...currentColors, colorB: "WHITE" }))}
      >
        CLICK ME
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a minor syntax error in the statement

```
 const App = () => {


  const [colors, setColors] = useState({ colorA: 'RED', colorB: 'PURPLE' });

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{colors.colorB}</span>
      <button onClick={
        () =>
          setColors(
            { ...colors,colorB: 'WHITE' }
          )
      }>CLICK ME</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```