# Is it good Practice to Stringify Object for useState() Hook To Avoid Re-Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150783/react-hooks-usestate-with-object) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638938/updating-an-object-with-setstate-in-react) question the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) seems to be used for updating an object managed in a `useState` hook.

I created a super simple example and found out, that even when the content of the object does not change, a re-render is triggered (which is clear, because the object changed):

```
import React from "react";

function useFriendStatus() {
  const [person, setPersonProps] = React.useState({name:'Mark',age:23});

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("rerender");
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setPersonProps({...person});   //simply set the object again -> no content changed
      console.log('update');
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [person]);


  return person;
}

export default function App() {
  const person = useFriendStatus();

  return <div className="App">Hello World: {"" + person.name}</div>;
}
```

Here you see a screenshot from my profiler which shows that a re-rendering seems to be fired (even if the displayed name did not change):

[image]

I am wondering if this is a "good practice" as EVERYTHING seems to be re-rendered. Sometimes you get deeply nested objects from an API and breaking them down to super-simple non-object `userState` hooks is not possible.

Wouldn't it be better to Stringify everything?

```
import React from "react";


function useFriendStatus() {
  const [person, setPersonProps] = React.useState(JSON.stringify({name:'Mark',age:23}));

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("rerender");
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const personCopy=JSON.parse(person);
      setPersonProps(JSON.stringify({...personCopy}));
      console.log('update');
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [person]);


  return person;
}

export default function App() {
  const person = JSON.parse(useFriendStatus());

  return <div className="App">Hello World: {"" + person.name}</div>;
}
```

How do you handle that in practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I created a super simple example and found out, that even when the content of the object does not change, a re-render is triggered (which is clear, because the object changed)

It has nothing to do with the "content" of the object, your component re-renderers because you create a shallow copy `{...person}` of an object (changing its reference).

On render phase React makes a **shallow comparison** with the previous state in order to decide if render will occur, and in javascript, `{} === {}` is always false.

> the spread operator seems to be used for updating an object managed in a useState hook.

As the state should be treated as [immutable](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data) it is common to use the spread operator to make a shallow copy.

> "It should only re-render if the name property of the object changes"

It is common to just add a condition before calling `setState`:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const newPerson = { ...person }; // fetch from some source
  // or check if person.name !== newPerson.name
  if (!isEqual(person, newPerson)) {
    setPerson(newPerson);
  }
}, [person]);
```

Comment: It is clear for me "why" the re-rendering is executed but I want to know "how" I can prevent it...

Comment: @user3579222 [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

Comment: What is the expected behavior of your example? Using stringify for comparing strings is not the same as comparing objects

Comment: It should only re-render if the name property of the object changes

Comment: I updating the answer

Comment: So would you consider the stringify approach as an alternative or do you see any systematic drawbacks?

Comment: It depends on the situation, you should research about `stringify` performance