# React hooks: useState/context; Cannot read property 'avatar' of undefined/How to update a nested object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, use-state

I have passed down a state variable and function from a context file:

UserContext:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const UserContext = React.createContext();

function UserProvider({ children }) {
  var [userImages, setUserImages] = useState({
    avatar: '/static/uploads/profile-avatars/placeholder.jpg'
  });

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        userImages,
        setUserImages
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default UserContext;

export { UserProvider };
```

At this point `UserImages` is just an object with one prop i.e. `avatar`

This is my App which is being wrapped by the Provider (please disregard the redux implementation, I just wanted to try Context)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { UserProvider } from './UserContext';
import App from 'next/app';
import withRedux from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';

import reduxStore from '../store/index';

import withReactRouter from '../with-react-router/with-react-router';


class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    const pageProps = Component.getInitialProps
      ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
      : {};
    return { pageProps };
  }
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, store } = this.props;

    return (
      <UserProvider>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <PersistGate persistor={store.__PERSISTOR} loading={null}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
      </UserProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to update some context using a setState function following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150783/react-hooks-usestate-with-object)

However I still get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'avatar' of undefined`

This is the shape of the state object:

```
userData:
setUserImages: ƒ ()
userImages:
avatar: "/static/uploads/profile-avatars/placeholder.jpg"
```

or

```
userData : {
  setUserImages : SetUserImages function,
  userImages : {
  avatar : "/static/uploads/profile-avatars/placeholder.jpg"
  }
 }
```

My component:

```
 function ImageUploader({ userData }) {

  var { avatar } = userData.userImages;
  var setUserAvatar = userData.setUserImages;

  function avatarUpdater(avatarPath) {
    setUserAvatar({ userData: { ...userData.userImages.avatar, avatarPath } });
    }
  }
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: You might need to check to make sure `userData` and `userData.userImages` before getting `avatar ` from it.
Where is `userData ` come from? How is this question related to react-context?

Comment: @TonyNguyen You are right perhaps I should update my question, I added some context...

Comment: Where are you using `ImageUploader`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserProvider` is the root of your app, so you can directly get it  `{userImages, setUserImages}` in `ImageUploader`

```js
function ImageUploader() {
  const {userImages, setUserImages} = useContext(UserContext)
  const { avatar } = userImages;

  function avatarUpdater(avatarPath) {
     setUserImages({ avatar: avatarPath });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically its good practice to not expose the `setState` from your context. You wanna wrap it in an explicit method to update state, then add that method to your Provider. Something like:

```
const userContext = {
  avatar: userImages,
  updateAvatarUrl: (url) => {
    setUserImages(prevState => ({...prevState, avatar: url}))
  }
}

return <UserContext.Provider value={userContext}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>
```

Try adding a hook for your UserContext which you can consume inside your component.

In `UserContext` add

```
export const useUserContext = () => useContext(UserContext)
```

Then inside your component:

```
import { useUserContext } from '<UserContext import>'

...

function avatarUpdater(avatarPath) {
    userCtx.updateAvatarUrl(avatarPath)
}
```

Cleanest structure for Context in my opinion. Allows for more precise control over context state.