# React Native setState/useState of an Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, use-state

I am new to React Native and don't quite understand the concept of initial states of an object and updating the state when I have more than one property to set.

the error (edit #2):

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {userRole}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

App.js

```
const initialLoginState = {
    userRole: null,
    userId: null,
};

const [user, setUser] = useState(initialLoginState);
const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

const restoreUser = async () => {
    const user = await authStorage.getUser();
    if (user) setUser(user);
};

if (!isReady) {
    return (
        <AppLoading
            startAsync={restoreUser}
            onFinish={() => setIsReady(true)}
            onError={console.warn}
        />
    );
}

//render
return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
        <NavigationContainer>
            {user.userRole ? <ViewTest /> : <AuthNavigator />}
        </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
);
```

useAuth which updates the user when I received the data:

```
const logIn = (data, authToken) => {
        setUser((prevState) => ({
            userRole: {
                ...prevState.userId, 
                userRole: data.USERROLE,
            },
        }));
        authStorage.storeToken(data.USERID);
    };
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with `initialise first state`?

Comment: I want my state object to have properties as shown above in `initialLoginState` so I can use it to conditionally render the component.

Comment: Something similar when setting the counter like `const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)` and then `setCounter(counter + 1)` to increment, but I need it with an object that has properties

Comment: if your issue just that `setUser` return an error because `prevState.userId` can be null? the rest is fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks useState() with Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150783/react-hooks-usestate-with-object)

Comment: my issue is with the initial useState. For some reason I get an error that I can't use it like `const [user, setUser] = useState(initialLoginState)`.  Undefined for user.userRole when rendering an object

Comment: in you case you probably want  ```setUser({...user, userID: data.USERID})```

Comment: can you please post the error here

Comment: yes, ill modify the question to be more clear now.

Comment: you may want to share more code, in particular where `user` is coming from

Comment: @Federkun  updated the whole question, it is the problem with the `setUser`

Comment: yeah, i assume you have the issue on log in? `setUser(user => ({ ...user, userId: data.USERID, userRole: data.USERROLE }))` - check other places where you modify the user's state as well. For example, `authStorage.getUser()` may return just the user id, not the full object that you expect in the rest of the app

Comment: I return the whole user object and it is not modified anywhere else. May it be in the setUser when I only update one property?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need prevState in functional component. user is the prevState before you set new state

```js
const logIn = (data, authToken) => {
  setUser({...user, userRole: data.USERROLE});
  authStorage.storeToken(data.USERID);
};
```

Comment: Slightly different error, but still... `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {0, 1, userRole}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: I think the problem is within 2 components you are rendering. Can you share <ViewTest> component?

Comment: it is not the problem even if I replace it with `View` of different colors. The screens won't change. The problem is somewhere in Context...

Answer (score 1):

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {userRole}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>  // <---- the problem is here
        <NavigationContainer>
            {user.userRole ? <ViewTest /> : <AuthNavigator />}
        </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
```

I'm not sure what **AuthContext.Provider** is, but it's trying to render the object(User) as html react elements, make sure you know what sort of data the **value** prop of that component takes.

Comment: Context provider's value allows me to see the changes in the value property. setUser is accessible across components if I use `useContext`. But you are right, if I use different values to render the screen, it works fine...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the right answer with the help of @P.hunter, @Erdenezaya and @Federkun.

The problem was in the state init and setUser().

1. App.js

```
    const initialLoginState = {
        userRole: null,
        userId: null,
    };

    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        initialLoginState,
    });
    const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

    const restoreUser = async () => {
        const user = await authStorage.getUser();
        if (user) setUser(user);
    };

    if (!isReady) {
        return (
            <AppLoading
                startAsync={restoreUser}
                onFinish={() => setIsReady(true)}
                onError={console.warn}
            />
        );
    }

    //syntax error was found in {user.userRole}
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
            <NavigationContainer>
                {user.userRole ? <ViewTest /> : <AuthNavigator />}
            </NavigationContainer>
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
```

2. Context functionality for setting the user had to be done like this:

```
export default useAuth = () => {
    const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

    const logIn = (data, authToken) => {

        setUser({ ...user, userRole: data.USERROLE });

        authStorage.storeToken(data.USERID);
    };

    const logOut = () => {
        setUser({ ...user, userRole: null });
        authStorage.removeToken();
    };

    return { user, logIn, logOut };
};
```

Thank you all for your help!