# Change the values in array based on some other value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example the original array is

```
const [leads,setLeads] = useState([
  { name:"something", otherValue:"something",stage:["Converted","Rejected","Refunded"]},
  { name:"something2", otherValue:"something2", stage:["Converted w/o demo","Rejected","Refunded"] },
  { name:"something3", otherValue:"something3",stage:["Rejected","Refunded"]}
])
```

**Here is what should happen**

Now if the stage includes **Converted** or **Converted w/o demo** a field should be added named converted with a value if true or if it does not includes either of both converted should be set to false

**Basically the desired result should be**

```
 [{ name:"something",  otherValue:"something",stage:["Converted","Rejected","Refunded"],converted :true},
  { name:"something2", otherValue:"something2", stage:["Converted w/o demo","Rejected"],converted: true},
  { name:"something3", otherValue:"something3",stage:["Rejected","Refunded"], converted:false}]
```

The value should be set using set using setLeads function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150783/react-hooks-usestate-with-object You can refer to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a callback function to useState where you add the additional property after processing the initial array and return the resultant array to be set into state for the first time.

For processing the array, you can use `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.prototype.includes`

Post this any update to the state will need to take care of this property update too

```
const arr = [
  { name:"something", otherValue:"something",stage:["Converted","Rejected","Refunded"},
  { name:"something2", otherValue:"something2", stage:["Converted w/o demo","Rejected","Refunded" },
  { name:"something3", otherValue:"something3",stage:["Rejected","Refunded"],
]
const getInitialState = () => {
  return arr.map(item => {
      if(item.stage.includes('Converted w/o demo') || item.stage.includes('Converted')) {
         return { ...item, converted: true}
      } else {
         return { ...item, converted: false}
      }

  })
}
const [leads, setLeads] = useState(getInitialState)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = [
      {
        name: 'something',
        otherValue: 'something',
        stage: ['Converted', 'Rejected', 'Refunded'],
      },
      {
        name: 'something2',
        otherValue: 'something2',
        stage: ['Converted w/o demo', 'Rejected', 'Refunded'],
      },
      {
        name: 'something3',
        otherValue: 'something3',
        stage: ['Rejected', 'Refunded'],
      },
    ];

    array.map((data, index) => {
      if (data.stage.indexOf('Converted')) {
        array[index].converted = true;
      } else {
        array[index].converted = false;
      }
    });

    const [leads, setLeads] = useState(array);
```

// if `Converted` value exists in array then add `converted=true` otherwise `converted=false` . You can change the value accordingly above if statement `if (data.stage.indexOf('Converted'))`

```
// output
    [
        {
            "name": "something",
            "otherValue": "something",
            "stage": [
                "Converted",
                "Rejected",
                "Refunded"
            ],
            "converted": false
        },
        {
            "name": "something2",
            "otherValue": "something2",
            "stage": [
                "Converted w/o demo",
                "Rejected",
                "Refunded"
            ],
            "converted": true
        },
        {
            "name": "something3",
            "otherValue": "something3",
            "stage": [
                "Rejected",
                "Refunded"
            ],
            "converted": true
        }
    ]
```