# Updating State | object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

**I have below JSX -**

```
 <FormGroup>
                <Label for="exampleEmail" style={{fontWeight:"bold"}}>What is your e-mail address?</Label>
                <Input type="email" name="email" id="exampleEmail" onChange={(e)=>setStateForProperties(e)} />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
                <Label for="examplePassword" style={{fontWeight:"bold"}}>What is your password?</Label>
                <Input type="password" name="password" id="examplePassword" onChange={(e)=>setStateForProperties(e)}/>
 </FormGroup>
```

**State Declarations -**

```
  const iLoginCreds ={
    userName:'',
    password:''
  }
  const [loginCreds, setLoginCredentials] = useState(iLoginCreds)
```

**onChange Method changing state -**

```
  function setStateForProperties(e)
  {
    alert(e.target.id);
    switch (e.target.id) {
      case 'exampleEmail':
        setLoginCredentials(...loginCreds,{
          userName:e.target.value
        
        });
            
        break;

        case 'examplePassword':
        setLoginCredentials(... loginCreds,{
          password:e.target.value
        });
    
      default:
        break;
    }
    console.log(loginCreds);
  }
```

Error -

When I write anything in textbox (upon onchange event trigger) , I receive an error -

```
TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `destruct` the `previous object properties` and return a `new object` after merging with the new one.

```
setLoginCredentials({ ...loginCreds, ...{userName:e.target.value} })
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing this:

```js
setLoginCredentials(...loginCreds, {
  userName:e.target.value
});
```

, which passes in 2 arguments to `useState`, you should move the curly braces to surround `...loginCreds`, like so:

```js
setLoginCredentials({...loginCreds,
  userName:e.target.value
});
```

You should do the same for password.

This will change only one property on the object.
[React Hooks useState() with Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150783/react-hooks-usestate-with-object)