# Getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: reactjs

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

function News({ pageSize }) {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    article: [],
    page: 1
  }
  )

  const updateNews = async () => {
    let res = await axios.get(`https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?domains=wsj.com&apiKey=79b02b430c1946cd9c505d3f91d7aec6&page=${state.page}&pageSize=${pageSize}`);
    setState({ ...state, article: res.data.articles })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    updateNews()
  }, [])

  const handleNext = async () => {
    setState({ page: state.page + 1 })
    updateNews()
    console.log(state.page);
  }

  let data = Array.from(state.article)

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>News</h2>
      <button onClick={handleNext}>Next</button>
      {data.map((elements) => {
        return (
          <div key={elements.url} style={{ marginBottom: '2rem' }}>
            <div> {elements.description} </div>
            <div>{new Date(elements.publishedAt).toGMTString()}</div>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default News;
```

I can't display next page's data. I was able to display it when I had created multiple functions. But now as I'm trying to to clear the redundancy, I'm getting this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)).`

Pls help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React state is asynchronous, so updating state & then accessing it immediately will not work. Updated state is only available on the next render cycle.

The below does not work.

```
setState({ page: state.page + 1 })
updateNews() // page is still old value
```

Best solution is to keep the `currentPage` in the state in a different variable & add it to the `dependency array` of `useEffect`. This would ensure every time it changes, a re-render happens with new data.

```
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);

...

useEffect(() => {
    updateNews()
  }, [currentPage])

...

setCurrentPage(currentPage => currentPage + 1);
```

Comment: Oh i see. This is confusing, for me atleast as I've just started to work on React JS. So what if we want to create a single nested state with multiple objects in order to eliminate repetition, just like I did?

Comment: In that case, please see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150783/react-hooks-usestate-with-object

Comment: I've looked into it and it seems really informative! Thanks alot. :)

Comment: @SameerI You can mark this as answer if it solves your problem.