# state data not changing in the render/display

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, react-state

I want to change the property `amount` in a state object using buttons (increment and decrement). I checked using `console.log` and the property's value is changing when the buttons are clicked, but the displayed number is not changing. why is that? what am I doing wrong?

here's my code: ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-hill-yvbcn7?file=/src/App.js:0-864))

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const temp = {
      id: 1,
      name: "apple",
      amount: 10
    };
    setData(temp);
  }, []);

  const handleInc = () => {
    let temp = data;
    temp.amount++;
    console.log("increment", temp.amount);
    setData(temp);
  };
  const handleDec = () => {
    let temp = data;
    temp.amount--;
    console.log("decrement", temp.amount);
    setData(temp);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <label>name: {data.name}</label>
      <br />
      <label>amount: {data.amount}</label>
      <br />
      <Button onClick={handleDec}>Reduce</Button>
      <Button onClick={handleInc}>Increase</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks useState() with Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150783/react-hooks-usestate-with-object)

Answer (score 1):

```
let temp = data;
temp.amount++;
setData(temp);
```

does not update `data`, as `temp == data` even after `temp.amount++`.
The state setter accepts either a **new object** or a **state update callback**.
Since you are updating state using it's old value, you *need* a state update callback,
that returns a **new** object (via **cloning**).

```
setData((data)=> {
    let temp = {...data}; // or Object.assign({}, data);
    temp.amount++;
    return temp;
}
```

Likewise, for decrementing.

See https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-objects-in-state
and https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues here. First one is that you using object as your state and object is reference type. When you do `let temp = data` you just referecing the same exact "`data`" object using different variable (pointer) "`temp`". Simply speaking once you change property in one variable, it "changes" the other. Now that also means that whatever you do, `temp` will always be equal to `data` cause they are referencing the same object. So to React state it means that it never really changes in your case, when you do `setState` you passing the same exact reference, so React sees that nothing changed - so it doesn't trigger re-render. Hope it is clear.
Fix in this case is to create a copy of object, in your case it could be simply `setState({...temp})`

The second issue in your case is that you are not using functional `setState`, which in your case is needed. The way you wrote it, might lead to bugs and unexpected behaviours, basically whenever you need to modify the state based on previous state value - you need to use functional `setState`. There are a lot of topics on this, let me reference just one - https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b/

In your case correct solution would be `setState((prevState) => ({...prevState, amount: prevState.amount + 1}))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `Callback` with `useState` to resolve this bug.

```
  const handleInc = () => {
    setData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, amount: prevState.amount + 1 }));
  };

  const handleDec = () => {
    setData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, amount: prevState.amount - 1 }));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Take note of both of the other answers by Nice Books and Nikita Chayka they both touch on important topics that will help you avoid this issue in the future. If you want to update an object using states you need to reconstruct the entire object when you reset the object. I made a fork of your sandbox you can take a look at of a working example that should solve your issue [Forked sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-silence-6stxo7).

Also the docs reference this issue as well [Doc reference](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-objects-in-state#treat-state-as-read-only).

Please let me know if you need any additional information.