# Update an objects in state ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update the state in react app

```
state = {
  pickupAddress: {
    country: '',
    city: '',
    zipCode: '',
    street: '',
  },
  deliveryAddress: {
    country: '',
    city: '',
    zipCode: '',
    street: '',
  },
  parcel: {
    type: '',
    height: '',
    width: '',
    length: '',
    weight: '',
    quantity: '',
  },
};
```

The problem that i am facing is i cannot reach inside of the object with `e.target.pickupAddress.city` for example.
This is my onChange method

```
 onChange = (e) => this.setState({[
    e.target.pickupAddress.country]: e.target.pickupAddress.country
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating an object with setState in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638938/updating-an-object-with-setstate-in-react)

Comment: Try this,  
onChange = (e) => this.setState({
    this.state.pickupAddress.country: e.target.pickupAddress.country
});

Comment: @VikasYadav: That's exact same thing OP has posted in question

Comment: Where is your JSX and the element with this onChange on it? You can't make up properties on e.target like that, I thought e.target would be a standardised DOM Node structure?

Comment: The difference with the previous question is that i have multiple objects i want to be able to upgrade the state with one onChange method instead to have to make methods for all cases

Comment: @Dominic, it looks the same but it isn't.

Comment: Thank you for the help but i have found a away around it. I have made onChange  method for each object so I don't need to get inside of the main object : 
` onChangePickup = (e) => {
        const newPickupAddress = {...this.state.pickupAddress, [e.target.name]: e.target.value};
        this.setState({
            ...this.state, pickupAddress: newPickupAddress
        })
    };