# how to set value of a class property in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I access and set a dynamic `e.target.value` of a class with `setState`?

I've tried `this.setState({fields[e.target.name]: e.target.value});`

```js
class App extends Component  {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      fields: {
        name: ''
      }
    }
  }

  handleChange = e => this.setState({fields[e.target.name]: e.target.value});

  render() {
    const { fields } = this.state;
   
    return (
      <>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" onChange={this.handleChange} value={fields.name} />
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Nested state is anti-pattern in React: components' state should be kept flat, precisely to face the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 5):

This is a slightly similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638938/updating-an-object-with-setstate-in-react/43639228). There are two ways to update the object. And as others have said, nesting state like this is an antipattern. [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/3bjdoe/state_is_an_antipattern/) is a good read-up on why.

**1- Simplest one:**

First create a copy of `fields` then do the changes in that:

```
let fields = Object.assign({}, this.state.fields);    //creating copy of object
fields[e.target.name] =  e.target.value               //updating value
this.setState({fields});
```

Instead of using `Object.assign` we can also write it like this:

```
let fields = {...this.state.fields};
```

**2- Using [spread operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638938/updating-an-object-with-setstate-in-react/43639228)**:

```
  handleChange = e => {
    e.persist(); //need to make the values persist because of event pooling
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      fields: {
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    }))
  }
```

Comment: The OP wants to update the fields value using `e.target.value`, not just the `name` property of the `fields`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Changed the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 4):

You can't access a state property like this. A possible solution is to create a copy from the `fields`, modify the value and then set the new state, like below:

```
handleChange = e => {  
    // The line below creates a copy of the state, using the spread operator
    let fields = { ...this.state.fields };
    fields[e.target.name] =  e.target.value
    this.setState({fields});
}
```

Comment: I'd use `let fields = {...this.state.fields};` instead for simplicity

Comment: Or even `let fields = [ ... this.state.fields]`. Will add it to the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Beware, fields is an object, not an array!

Comment: @NinoFiliu I haven't noticed that, sorry