# How to update Nested state in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

how to update nested state in reactjs, such as I have an Array of an object of course

```
state = {
    courses: [
      { id: 1, coursename: "CSS3", like: 25, dislike: 0 },
      { id: 2, coursename: "Javascript", like: 45, dislike: 0 },
      { id: 3, coursename: "ReactJS", like: 294, dislike: 0 }
    ]
  };
```

now i want to update **like** on the particular course only on onClick  , after updating it should be 26 . and again if i click it should decremented by 1.

- **You can find the code in** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-field-zz8pw)

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43639228/11755375)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your handleLike method, you can map the courses and update the like field of the given course like this:

```
  handleLike = id => {
    console.log("id", id);
    const updatedCourses = this.state.courses.map(c => {
      if (c.id === id) {
        return {
          ...c,
          like: c.like + 1
        };
      } else {
        return c;
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      courses: updatedCourses
    });
  };
```