# setstate pattern to access an object's property in state (reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

If you have an object in the state,

```
state = {
  item: {
    name: ''
  }
}
```

How to use this design pattern to access the name property of the item object?

```
changeMe = (e) => this.setState( {[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
```

I tried changing the name to item.name but it just creates a state with item.name as key.

```
<Form.Control name="item.name" onChange={this.onChange} defaultValue={this.state.item.name}></Form.Control>
```

Comment: Take a look at the first answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638938/updating-an-object-with-setstate-in-react

Comment: Wow, thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access deeply nested properties in this way, you can either manually split the string then recursively index into the property, or use something off the shelf e.g. [`lodash.set`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.set)

```
import set from 'lodash.set';
...
changeMe = e => {
  const newState = set(this.state, e.target.name, e.target.value);
  this.setState(newState);
}
```

Comment: So I can't do it like how i wanted it to. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```js
changeMe = (e) => this.setState( { item: {[e.target.name]: e.target.value} });
```

Comment: You would also need to update the `name` of the target for this to work i.e. `name="name"` rather than `name="item.name"`

Comment: It works if the object only has 1 property. Somehow the item gets overwritten if i change another form field.

```
state = {
  item: {
    name: '',
    id: 0
  }
}
```
@James I already reverted it to name="name"