# Unable to change value in input onChange in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Following is a sample code to handle change in input values

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function MyName () {

    const [ formData, setFormData ] = useState(
        {
            name:'test',
            age:29,
            account: {
                card:3939939393,
                exp:2020
            }
        }
            )

    function handleChange1 (evt) {

        setFormData({
           ...formData , [evt.target.name]:evt.target.value
        });
    }

    function handleSubmit1 () {

        console.log(formData);


    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>My name is: {formData.name}</h1>
            <h1>My age is: {formData.age}</h1>
            <h1>My card is: {formData.account.card}</h1>
            <h1>My ex is: {formData.account.exp}</h1>

            <input name="name" type="text" value={formData.name} onChange={handleChange1} />
            <input name="age" type="text" value={formData.age} onChange={handleChange1} />
            <input name="card" type="text" value={formData.account.card} onChange={handleChange1} />
            <input name="exp" type="text" value={formData.account.exp} onChange={handleChange1} />


            <button onClick={handleSubmit1}>Click</button>


            <div>


            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyName
```

So for this example code
I was able to change the name and age values 
but the card and exp values I couldn't change value why  ??

when I wanted to add a new value of the card 
and also when I wanted to add a new value of exp
the input of (card, ex) became blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal, the exp and card values are not at the top of your object, but in a sub-object account.

For both of these fields, you should use an other function

```
function handleChange2 (evt) {

    setFormData({
       ...formData , account:{
           ...formData.account,
           [evt.target.name]:evt.target.value
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: First Thanks , this solution work 
 but the name and age they became blocked for change

Comment: You have to use the handleChange2 only for the acc and exp fields

Comment: `function handleChange1 (evt) {

        setFormData({
           ...formData,
           account : {
               ...formData.account,
               [evt.target.name]:evt.target.value
           }     
           , [evt.target.name]:evt.target.value
        });
    }`   i changed the function like this and works fine for both

Comment: You have to use handleChange1 for name and age field and use the new handleChange2 for the card and exp fields

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the nesting into `account`. The `name` and `age` are "direct" state variables, but `card` and `exp` belong to `account` and are therefore not correctly set with

```
setFormData({
  ...formData , [evt.target.name]:evt.target.value
});
```

So you'd need to catch these cases in your `setFormData`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are not copying the nested object values when you are setting the state. I would suggest you to re-write this as shown here: [Updating an object with setState in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638938/updating-an-object-with-setstate-in-react)
use the portion "updating nested state object".