# how to update a object state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

i have an object like this :

```
const [mile, setMile] = useState({
    AL: 0,
    AK: 0,
    AR: 0,
    CA: 0,
    CA: 0,
    CT: 0,
    DE: 0,
    DC: 0,
    FL: 0,
    GA: 0,
    HI: 0,
    ID: 0,
    IL: 0,
    IN: 0,
    IA: 0,
    KS: 0,
    KY: 0,
    LA: 0,
    ME: 0,
    MA: 0,
)};
```

and I receive an array of objects like in the image:
[Second object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1bOS.png)

i want to calculate miles  traveled  in every state  :

something like that , but i don't know how to split mile object , i tried Object.entries , but failed

```
secondObject.map(row =>{
 if (mile.key === row.state)
 {
  mile.value += row.Miles
 }
```

Comment: Your closing brackets are in reverse order, should close the object with } then close the hook with );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setState(prev => return newValue)`. When you update object, you have to be careful to return new object.

```js
setMile(prev => {
  // your can't update prev itself so make a copy
  const newMile = Object.assign({}, prev)
  secondObject.map(row => {
    if (newMile.hasOwnProperty(row.state) {
      newMile[row.state] += row.Miles
    }
  })
  return newMile  
})
```

Related
[Updating an object with setState in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638938/updating-an-object-with-setstate-in-react)
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
secondObject.map(row =>{
 if (mile.hasOwnProperty(row.state)){
  mile[row.state] += row.Miles
 }
});
```