# How can I update setState?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass `setChart` to `ChartType` and i want to update `setChart` in `ChartType` component.
so I tried to use array with null, but for some reason, I get this error : `TypeError: setChart is not a function`
so How can I update `setChart` to change the chart with a different div ??

ChartTypePage

```
const ChartTypePage = ({ changeLayout }) => {
const [chart, setChart] = useState([
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
  ]);
  
  const layout = [
    <Side id="first" key="a" onClick={chartItself}>
      <ChartType visible={visible[0]} setChart={setChart[0]} />
      {chart[0]}
    </Side>,
    <Side id="second" key="b" onClick={chartItself}>
      <ChartType visible={visible[1]} setChart={setChart[1]} />
      {chart[1]}
    </Side>,
    <Side id="third" key="c" onClick={chartItself}>
      <ChartType visible={visible[2]} setChart={setChart[2]} />
      {chart[2]}
    </Side>,
```

ChartType

```
const ChartType = ({ visible, setChart }) => {
const chartType = [
    <Bar
      key="p"
      data={chartData}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
    <Line
      key="p"
      data={chartData}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
    <Radar
      key="p"
      data={chartData}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />]
    return (
    <TypeBox visible={visible}>
      <div>
        <div onClick={() => setChart(chartType[0])}>
          <h3>Line</h3>
        </div>
        <div onClick={() => setChart(chartType[1])}>
          <h3>Bar</h3>
        </div>
        <div onClick={() => setChart(chartType[2])}>
          <h3>Radar</h3>
        </div>
        <div onClick={() => setChart(chartType[3])}>
          <h3>Pie</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </TypeBox>
  );
};

export default ChartType;
```

Comment: Within `setChart={setChart[1]}` you are passing down an element of the array which seems to be `null` to me. That's the reason why it's not a function.

Comment: @norbitrial - sounds like an answer to me!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638938/updating-an-object-with-setstate-in-react?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that `setChart` in the `ChartTypePage` parent component ***is*** a function, so `setChart[0]` doesn't make any sense, it's undefined.

## Solution

From what I can tell it seems like you want to pass a callback to the `ChartType` child component, `setChart={setChart}`. This is the state updater function that the children are invoking on `click`.

```
const layout = [
  <Side id="first" key="a" onClick={chartItself}>
    <ChartType visible={visible[0]} setChart={setChart} />
    {chart[0]}
  </Side>,
  ...
];
```

### Update

In the child component you are mutating the state invariant from an array (*where `chart[i]` is null*) to the type of `chartType[j]`. You likely really want to update a specific index in the `chart` array.

Example:

```
<div
  onClick={() => setChart(charts => charts.map(
    (chart, i) => i === 0 ? chartType[0] : chart,
  )}
>
  <h3>Line</h3>
</div>
```

This will lead to a lot of code duplication since each `onClick` callback function will essentially be the same except for the index you want to update. Abstract this into a function and define it in the parent and pass instead of the `setChart` callback.

Example:

This is a curried function that first takes an index to close over in scope and return a function that then takes a char type to also close over in scope and then finally return a function to be used as the attached callback.

Note how the index is closed over when passing to the child, and then the child closes over the chart type.

```
const updateChart = index => chartType => () => {
  setChart(charts => charts.map(
    (chart, i) => i === index ? chartType : chart,
  );
};

...

const layout = [
  <Side id="first" key="a" onClick={chartItself}>
    <ChartType visible={visible[0]} setChart={updateChart(0)} />
    {chart[0]}
  </Side>,
  ...
];
```

Child

```
<div onClick={setChart(chartType[0])}>
  <h3>Line</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sir! , I did as same as this answer but for some reason, `chart[0]` is undefined

Comment: @Somi On the initial render `chart[0]` is at least `null`. It's updated later. Is this what you are seeing? Also, when you update state in the child, shouldn't you be updating a specific index of the `chart` state? You've 8 elements in the `chart` array, but only 4 divs in the child.

Comment: it's null when I don't click to change `setChart` to `chartType[0]` but when I click it then it changes to `undefined`

Comment: @Somi Because you update `chart` state from an array to `chartType[0]` which is some JSX, and so then index `n` of the new value is now undefined.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir ! then How can I make it to be changed??

Comment: @Somi I just updated my answer to include my best guess at what and how you should try to update the state in the parent component.