# i try to push a value inside an object and its always show undefined everytime i switch to another input tag

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, object

sorry bug again. im new to reactjs, i try to implement functional component and have problem with push a data inside object. i have 2 input tag and everytime i fill a value inside and switch to another the other show undefined. im not sure what is happening in here. help me explain what happen and how to solve it. please advise , thank you so much. below here i put a picture and my code.

[my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGnLX.png)

```
function App() {
const [heldItems, setHeldItems] = useState({
    salesno: '',
    plu: '',
    price: '',
    dateandtime: '',
});
const [edit, setEdit] = useState({});
const [salesItemsTemp, setSalesItemsTemp] = useState([]);

const handlerOnEdit = (heldItemsData) => {
    console.log(heldItemsData);
    setHeldItems(heldItemsData);
    setEdit(heldItemsData);
};

const handlerOnChange = (e, type) => {
    setHeldItems({
        [type]: e.target.value,
    });
};

useEffect(() => console.log(heldItems));

const handlerOnSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
        salesno: uniqid(),
        plu: heldItems.plu,
        price: heldItems.price,
        dateandtime: new Date().toLocaleString(),
    };

    console.log(data);

};

const handlerRemove = (heldItemsSalesNo) => {
    let filteredSalesItemsTemp = salesItemsTemp.filter(
        (item) => {
            return item.salesno !== heldItemsSalesNo;
        },
    );
    setSalesItemsTemp(filteredSalesItemsTemp);
};

return (
    <>
        <form onSubmit={handlerOnSubmit} autoComplete="off">
            <h1>GoGreen Point Of Sales</h1>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Input item name"
                name="plu"
                onChange={(e) => handlerOnChange(e, 'plu')}
                value={heldItems.plu}
            />
            PLU
            <input
                type="number"
                placeholder="Input item price"
                name="price"
                onChange={(e) => handlerOnChange(e, 'price')}
                value={heldItems.price}
            />
            Price
            <button type="submit">
                {edit.salesno ? 'Save Edit Item' : 'Save Item'}
            </button>
            <div>
                <table>
                    <caption>Sales</caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>SalesNo</th>
                            <th>PLUName</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Date & Time</th>
                            <th>Void</th>
                            <th>Edit</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {salesItemsTemp.map((sales) => {
                            const { salesno, plu, price, dateandtime } =
                                sales;
                            return (
                                <tr key={salesno}>
                                    <td>{salesno}</td>
                                    <td>{plu}</td>
                                    <td>{price}</td>
                                    <td>{dateandtime}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button
                                            type="button"
                                            onClick={() =>
                                                handlerRemove(salesno)
                                            }>
                                            X
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button
                                            type="button"
                                            onClick={() =>
                                                handlerOnEdit(sales)
                                            }>
                                            Edit
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            );
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td>brought to you by ...</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>
    </>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the complete object. The following may help:

```
const handlerOnChange = (e, type) => {
  setHeldItems((prevValue)=>({...prevValue,
    [type]: e.target.value,
  }));
};
```

Comment: thank you so much your advise works very well.

Answer (score 1):

In your `handlerOnChange` you're replacing the previous state with a new object which has only one property, so you've lost your previous state. To fix it use `handlerOnChange` like this:

```
const handlerOnChange = (e, type) => {
    setHeldItems(prevState => ({
       ...prevState,
      [type]: e.target.value,
    }));
 };
```

Comment: thank you so much your advise works very well.

Comment: You're welcome.I would appreciate it to git upvote to my response.

Comment: Right, thank you.

Comment: you guys awesome. thanks for comin :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that inside your `handlerOnChnage` method you replace the previous state, with new state and thus the previous state is lost!! Yes all those 4 types are lost and you are left with just one!!

You wanna preserve the previous state, sure? Then you can do that too..

## Never Do this

You might find some solution like :

```
const handlerOnChange = (e, type) => {
setHeldItems({
     ...heldItems,
    [type]: e.target.value,
  });
};
```

Since the set state is asynchronous you can't expect the state to be updated just after `setHelditems` gets executed. Want more detail on it ? [Visit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42038724/7699452)

## More clean solution

Do we have a proper solution? Yes and here it is : Use a callback function and update the state with the use of that

```
const handlerOnChange = (e, type) => {
  setHeldItems(prevSnapshot=>({...prenSnapshot,
    [type]: e.target.value,
  }));
};
```

[Helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638938/updating-an-object-with-setstate-in-react)

Comment: thank you so much your advise works very well.