# How do i update an array in an object using useState in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How would I go about updating an array inside of an object using useState. My hook looks something like this:

```js
const [currentUser, setcurrentUser] = useState({firstname:"adam" , classes:["discrete", "calc 2", "physics"]});
```

I've been trying to set currentUser.classes equal to a new array of classes but been running into errors.

Comment: What have you tried? What errors are you running into?

Comment: ive tried"currentUser.classes = someNewArray" which hasnt seemed to work for me. I have ran into a weird error saying "typeError: h is not a function" I believe its because i was trying "setCurrentUser(currentUser)". the reasons i tried that was because the page wasnt rerendering after editing the array

Comment: Can you paste the state trace in the question? On a side note, you should be updating a state using its setter. Example: `setCurrentUser(o => ({...o, classes: someNewArray}))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating an object with setState in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638938/updating-an-object-with-setstate-in-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this method.. If you are still facing issues just let me know..

```
const [currentUser, setcurrentUser] = useState({firstname:"adam" , classes:["discrete", "calc 2", "physics"]});

const newArray = ["Good", "Bad", "Neutral"]

useEffect(()=>{
setCurrentUser({...currentUser,classes:newArray})
},[currentUser])
```

in the above method... I use react hook useEffect to change the value of current User classes..

Comment: This will trigger an infinite loop. no need for dependency in the useEffect

Comment: This seemed to do the trick thank you i wasnt aware of the "...currentUser".

Comment: i didnt use the useEffect though. but the set current user works great

Comment: I just give an example, so sorry for pass any dependency inside useEffect array..

Answer (score 0):

Couple things to remember when dealing with objects in JavaScript. If you try changing the value of `currentUser` directly, like `currentUser.firstname = "joe"` the React state won't update.

Here is a CodeSandbox to give you an example of what you are trying to do
https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-browser-gdkvkm?file=/src/App.tsx:235-303

This is the key part

`setcurrentUser((oldVal) => ({ ...oldVal, classes: ["new class"] }));`

What is happening here is that you can use `setcurrentUser` to get the old value, then create a new object with the old values and whatever changes you want to make.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

The spread operator makes this pretty easy, `...oldVal` basically copies the values of the current object, and then we overwrite `classes`