Need to update a state variable using setValue in axios which is initialized as a object
Hi I am learning React
Please go through my code, How do I set the state of a get response in axios?
const [state, setState] = useState({
    bookingId: '', // This will contain booking ID from Input Field
    bookingData: null, // This will contain booking data received from axios
    infoMessage: ''
})

const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios.get(url + state.bookingId).then((response.data) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setState({ bookingData: response.data });
        setState({ infoMessage: '' });
        console.log(state)
    }).then((error) => {
        setState({ bookingData: '' });
        setState({ infoMessage: `${state.bookingId} Not Found` });
    })
})

<tr>
    <td>{state.bookingData.id}</td>
    <td>{state.bookingData.emailId}</td>
</tr>

I referred this thread How to set state of response from axios in react
But I couldn't find a solution, still I am unable to get the response data inside state value

Calling setState with an object will replace the previous state entirely, not merge it. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638938/updating-an-object-with-setstate-in-react

Is your onSubmit handler function submitting a data to a backend API or are you trying to get a data from an API endpoint after submitting? Can you include the code to your form input to be able to understand what you want to achieve better?


Please format the code block before posting.
Please read further about how a change in state results in new data being rendered.
Read about String interpolation vs Concatenation.
Read about promise in JavaScript.

Lets check the code,

Response handling: Instead of response.data use response as the parameter in the .then callback

.then((response) => {
   setState(prevState => ({
   ...prevState,
   bookingData: response.data,
   infoMessage: ''
}));


Error Handling: Use .catch for error handling instead of chaining another .then.

.catch((error) => {
  // handle error  
}

For setting the state, you can do it something like
setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  bookingData: null,
  infoMessage: `${state.bookingId} Not Found`
}));

Do a quick google search to see how the above block works, or refer the link posted by Antonija

You can set State value in React by this two ways:

Assign it in single object with all properties:

axios.get(url + state.bookingId).then((response.data) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    setState({
        bookingId: '',
        bookingData: response.data,
        infoMessage: ''
    });
    console.log(state)
}).then((error) => {
    setState({
        bookingId: '',
        bookingData: '',
        infoMessage: `${state.bookingId} Not Found`
    });
});


Use Spread Operator to assign single properties:

axios.get(url + state.bookingId).then((response.data) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    setState({ ...state, bookingData: response.data });
    setState({ ...state, infoMessage: '' });
    console.log(state)
}).then((error) => {
    setState({ ...state, bookingData: '' });
    setState({ ...state, infoMessage: `${state.bookingId} Not Found` });
});

