# Javacsript - access nested object value using 2 variable keys (for ReactJS setState())

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

This seems to me to be a very simple issue but I can't seem to solve it.

I am trying to setState on a ReactJS component while accessing the nest state object using 2 string keys but I cannot seem to get this to work.

State: -

```
state = {
    first_name: {
      value: '',
    },
}
```

These attempts fail: -

```
this.setState({ [[e.target.name]['value']]: e.target.value})
this.setState({ [e.target.name['value']]: e.target.value})
```

e.target.name evaluates to 'first_name' so that is not the issue... I have also tried: -

```
this.setState({ [['first_name']['value']]: e.target.value})
this.setState({ ['first_name'['value']]: e.target.value})
```

All that happens is I get a new entry in the state object of "undefined". Can anyone give advice here? Thanks.

Edited:

Appears to be a duplicate of: -

[How do I setState for nested array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34956479/how-do-i-setstate-for-nested-array)

Answer (score 0):

Solution found (using the spread operator)...

```
this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: {
      ...this.state[e.target.name],
      value: e.target.value
    },
  }
)
```