# How to I fill a nested array with setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What this code is essentially supposed to do is concatenate an empty array object On Click with the add function. Then, I want to fill concatenate each sub array individually depending on the index of the sub Click. So each subList has its own Click to add elements to itself.

The problem is that I keep getting the wrong output when I use setState to update the inner subList. This doesn't happen when I mutate state directly, When I mutate state directly, I get correct results in the console window as intended.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

//onClick: push an array object onto List
//On Sub Click: Fill the inner arrays individually

class AppTest extends Component {

  state = {
    List: [
      {subList: []}
    ]
  }
```

this function concatenates an array object each time it is clicked.

```
  add = (event) => {
    this.setState(
      {List: this.state.List.concat({subList: []})}
    );
  }
```

this function grabs the current index of the List and ATTEMPTS to fill each subList individually
based on the index being clicked.

```
 subadd = (i, event) => {

    this.setState(
      {List: [
        {subList: this.state.List[i].subList.concat(0)}
      ]}
    );

    //When I mutate state directly, The entire code works as intended: Uncomment below 
    //to take a look

    //this.state.List[i].subList = this.state.List[i].subList.concat(0);

    //This is a nested loop that prints the contents of the entire array (including sublists) to the console
    for(let i = 0; i < this.state.List.length; i++)
    {
      console.log(i + "a");
      for(let j = 0; j < this.state.List[i].subList.length; j++)
      {
        console.log(j + "b");
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      //My end game is to output input tabs for each element INCLUDING the subList elements in between the main
      // List elements
        <div>
        {this.state.List.map(i => {
          return(
            <div>
              <input value = "Init"/><br />
              <div onClick = {this.subadd.bind(this, this.state.List.indexOf(i))}>subClick</div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <div onClick = {this.add}>Click</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AppTest;

/*
  All inputs will output the same result: 0a, 0b, 1a, 2a, 3a ...

  The length of how many elements are printed is simply the current length of the list.
*/
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34956479/how-do-i-setstate-for-nested-array

Comment: That example is not a nested array. But a nested object. I tried this already and it doesn't help my case.

Comment: Is there anything else I can post to help?

Comment: You can use the spread operator with arrays too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can spread the array similar to how you do an Object, as arrays are objects in javascript.

Please find the code here - https://codesandbox.io/s/l4z5z47657

```
//spread array to new object with the Object keys starting from 0 corresponding to each element in array
    let tempArray = { ...this.state.List };
//get the array that we need to change and concat to the sublist
        let newSubList = tempArray[i];
        newSubList.subList = newSubList.subList.concat(0);
//create new array and update the index with new value . Note the special syntax with [i].
//This is because we have spread an array and not an Object
        let toChange = { ...tempArray, [i]: newSubList };

//COnvert the Object to array again
        toChange = Object.values(toChange);
        this.setState({ List: toChange });
        console.log(this.state.List);
```

This will immutably update the state. You may be able to further reduce the number of lines, but use this as a start.

Comment: thank you! I had a feeling that the spread operator was involved. This look like it can work, i will try it when I get home.