# How to save state in a deep nested object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a JSON file that stored in state. Now I need to update a value in that file. When I use setState it doesn't save anything. this.state.data is an array that contains 4 objects. Where I'm doing a mistake?

this is my state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: null,
    }
  }
```

Now I'm trying to save the value in data

```
this.setState({
      [data[index].settings[idSettings].settings._init_[idMessageContent]
        .message_content]: newValue,
    })
```

Comment: can you share json object for better undesrstanding @Yerlan

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34956479/how-do-i-setstate-for-nested-object?

Answer (score 1):

```
[data[index].settings[idSettings].settings._init_[idMessageContent].message_content] ~ [oldValue]
```

And what you did is

```
this.setState({[oldValue]: newValue})
```

This means you set a new property with the name is [oldvalue] for the state. You should clone `data` to a new object and mutate that object. Then assign the whole new object to `state`

```
// Deep clone the object
const newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.data))
// Mutating the new object
newData[index].settings[idSettings].settings._init_[idMessageContent].message_content = newVlaue
// Assign the new object to state
this.setState({data: newData})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **avoid** mutation at all i can suggest you several solutions listed below.

One solution is to manually spread every layer of object like so.

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
  users: {
    ...prevState.users,
    john: {
      ...prevState.users.john,
      status: {
        ...prevState.users.john.status
        /* ... */
      } 
    }
  }
}))
```

But it seems very complicated and unreadable.

The solution that I prefer is to write own utility function to do it for you OR you can use already existing and well-tested function like `assocPath` from Ramda.js or similar from other libraries (e.g. Lodash etc.)

```
this.setState(R.assocPath([ 'users', 'john', 'status', ...], newPropValue))
```