# ReactJS - Get data from multiple TextField (unknown quantity) then setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textfield

I have a list of columns, they are rendered as TextFields:

```
{columns.map((column, index) => (
    <TextField
        key={index}
        margin="dense"
        id={column}
        label={column}
        name={column}
        type="text"
        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        fullWidth/> 
    ))}
```

and handleInputChange function is written as below:

```
handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      addData: {
        [this.state.fullName]:{
            [name]: value
        }
      }
    });
}
```

The data that I want to receive is:

```
addData: {
    [name-of-column-1]: value,
    [name-of-column-2]: value,
    [name-of-column-3]: value,
    .......
}
```

but the handleInputChange function overrides after every TextField change, the data that I received:

```
addData: {
    [name-of-column-1 (or 2, 3...)]: value,
}
```

Is there any way to get the data I need? Thanks everyone!

Comment: you should change this part of code  [this.state.fullName]:{
            [name]: value
        }

Comment: Yes, how do I fix it?

Comment: can you provide your state ?

Comment: I think you need dynamic key name for your state

Comment: checkout this one bro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280445/reactjs-setstate-with-a-dynamic-key-name?rq=1

Comment: Thanks so much bro! I found the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How do I setState for nested object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34956479/how-do-i-setstate-for-nested-object)

```
handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      addData: {
        [this.state.fullName]:{
            ...this.state.addData[this.state.fullName],
            [name]: value,
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning whole new object every time value from one TextField changes and not retaining old values from state.

I'm not sure what exactly is `this.state.fullName`, but in order to have your desired state structure you can implement it like this:

```
handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      addData: {
        ...this.state.addData,
        [name]: value
      }
    });
}
```

When destructing `this.state.addData` (with `...`), you are basically assigning all of its properties to the new object and then adding additional `[name]: value`. Its important to put destruction above new assignment in order to update latest value.

Comment: Yes, but in my case it look like this: ...this.state.addData[this.state.fullName] Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

This's a issue when you setState. When you using

```
this.setState({
      addData: {
        [this.state.fullName]:{
            [name]: value
        }
      }
    });
```

that mean you are setting a new state just have one nested object

```
addData { abc: value }
```

so the old values are lost. You need add them before you change the new value. Try this

```
handleInputChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    const newData = {...this.state.addData};
    newData[name] = value;

    this.setState({ addData: newData });
}
```

or

```
handleInputChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    this.setState({
        addData: {
            ...this.state.addData,
            [name]: value
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can not change state  const { addData } = this.state;
    addData[name] = value; in this way

Comment: u r changing object inside state without setState

Comment: it happens bro. Good luck

Comment: This way is right, but in my case the newState must be like this: const newData = {...this.state.addData[this.state.fullName}; Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

**I think you should prepare your data first and set it into your state or try in this way**

```
this.setState({
      addData: {
        [...this.state.fullName]:{
            [name]: value
        }
      }
    });
```