# useState change only one value in array

Tags: reactjs, use-state

Have an array of pairs, and am using separate filter functions to change the array value. But I'm struggling to only change a single value while retaining the existing ones.

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
        fur: '',
        expression: ''
    })

const filterFur = (fur) => e => {
        setFilters({
            fur: fur
        })
    }

    const filterExpression = (expression) => e => {
        setFilters({
            expression: expression
        })
    }
    
    ...
    
    <label className="label"> 
       <input type="radio" name="checkbox" value="All Furs" onClick={filters.fur === '' ? null : filterFur('')}/> All
    </label>
```

When `onClick` triggers the function, it sets `fur` to the desired value, but removes `expression` entirely. How would I keep the `expression` value, while changing only `fur`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the [spread operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34956479/how-do-i-setstate-for-nested-object) to modify the desired parts of state and copy the other parts:

```
setFilters({ ...filters, fur: fur });
setFilters({ ...filters, expression: expression });
```

Here is some more official documentation:
https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the silly question.